# Xcode shows labels, buttons, navigation bar & images as pixelated

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

As you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

The Navigation bar, buttons and the speaker image are pixeled.
I migth think that it has a connection to the View Hierarchy - this View is on top of the main View (The main view label and buttons looks good and not pixeled), written in Swift:

```
var navUser = UIViewController()

class ViewControllerMenu: UIViewController {
 navUser = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navUser")
        addChildViewController(navUser)
        navUser.view.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(navUser.view)
        navUser.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        navUser.view.alpha = 0

        navUser.view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        navUser.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        navUser.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        navUser.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10

        navUser.view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: navUser.view.bounds).cgPath
        navUser.view.layer.shouldRasterize = true
}
```

I'm adding the View Hierarchy of this view:

[image]

This happens in all the Xcode iPhone simulators and in my personal iPhone 7.

Comment: What happens if you simply comment out the `navUser.view.layer.shouldRasterize = true` line? Seems like an odd usage of `.shouldRasterize`...

Comment: @DonMag Yes it works! Please post it as an answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an odd usage of `.shouldRasterize` ... that is normally used when re-displaying a complex view / layer multiple times (such as game animation).

Removing that line - `navUser.view.layer.shouldRasterize = true` - should fix the problem.